# RecyclerView not populating, likely a silly adapter problem

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I used a working `RecyclerView` as a template for another, but I made some sort of mistake in its implementation and I can't find it. Here is the code that initializes the view:

```
 mMessageThreadList = new ArrayList<>();       
 mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.chat_list_recycler_view);


 private void initRecyclerView() {
        Log.d(TAG, "initRecyclerView Called");

        //Initializes and sets up adapter

        mAdapter = new ChatListRecyclerViewAdapter(mThreadList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        Query query = mThreadCollection;
        query.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                for (DocumentChange documentChange : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                    switch (documentChange.getType()) {
                        case ADDED:
                            Thread thread = documentChange.getDocument().toObject(Thread.class);
                            Log.d(TAG, "Last Message: " + thread.getLastMessage().getMessage());

                            mThreadList.add(thread);
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Note that the print log statement in the `SnapshotListener` does contain a value when printed so the information is returning from Firebase, it's just not displaying. Which makes me think my problem is with my Adapter/Viewholder:

```
public class ChatListRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChatListRecyclerViewAdapter.ChatListViewHolder> {

    private List<Thread> threadList;

    ChatListRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Thread> threadList) {
        this.threadList = threadList;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ChatListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_list_row, parent, false);
        return new ChatListViewHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ChatListViewHolder holder, int position) {

        // This method fills fields with data for each list item
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewholder called");

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM hh:mm a");
        final Thread thread = threadList.get(position);
        char initial = thread.getPartnerName().charAt(0);
        char uppercaseInitial = Character.toUpperCase(initial);

        Log.d(TAG, thread.getLastMessage() + " " + thread.getPartnerID());


        holder.partnerName.setText(thread.getPartnerName());
        holder.authorInitial.setText(uppercaseInitial);
        holder.lastMessageText.setText(thread.getLastMessage().getMessage());
        holder.lastMessageTime.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(thread.getLastMessage().getTimestamp()));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return threadList.size();
    }

    //Viewholder stores the information about the layout and content of each list item, and serves as a template for each item of a RecyclerView


    public class ChatListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView partnerName;
        TextView authorInitial;
        TextView lastMessageText;
        TextView lastMessageTime;
        LinearLayout listTextHolder;

        public ChatListViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            partnerName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.partner_name);
            authorInitial = itemView.findViewById(R.id.partner_initial);
            lastMessageText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.last_message);
            lastMessageTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.last_message_time);
            listTextHolder = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_text_holder);

        }
    }
}
```

chat_list_row.xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/single_thread_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/partner_initial"
        android:background="@drawable/chat_list_circle"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="A"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/last_message_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_extralight"
        android:text="@string/sample_time"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:typeface="normal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_text_holder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/partner_initial"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/partner_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/nunito"
            android:text="@string/sample_name"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/last_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_extralight"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:text="@string/sample_message"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:typeface="normal" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Edit: Layout of the Activity that `RecyclerView` appears in. I also edit above code to show where the variable is attached to the view:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    tools:context="org.andrewedgar.theo.ChatListActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/chat_list_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/chat_list_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chat_list_toolbar" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/new_check_in_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_person_pin_circle_black_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You should check if FirebaseFirestoreException e is not equal null before doing any operation to gain time

Comment: Could you post your chat_list_row layout please?

Comment: Posted. There is no exception. The information is getting pulled down.

Comment: You should rename your custom `Thread` class, when people see it they usually think about `java.lang.Thread` which is one of the core classes. Especially since your code sample does not include your imports.

Comment: Code looks normal to me.. any chance that your recycler view is just not visible?

Comment: What's the layout that the RecyclerView is in?

Comment: I renamed the Thread class for clarity. I also posted the xml file of the activity the RecyclerView appears in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have missed to add layout manager of RecyclerView. Would you please add this and try again

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Comment: This was it. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome. Happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your recyclerview is not showing any data because the list in adapter is still empty. After fetching data from firebase you are adding to mThreadList, which is still with activity and not adapter. To update the list in adapter you can add a method in adapter class and pass the list to adapter and notifyDataseChanged there.

Activity:

```
 //after firebase task...
 mAdapter.updateData(mThreadList);
```

Adapter: add new method

```
void updateData(List<Thread> threadList){
  this.threadList = threadList;
  notifyDatasetChanged();     //notify adapter that new list is added
}
```